# Set vertical distance between two uibuttons using autolayout constraints

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, autolayout

I would like `ButtonA` to stay where it is, and `ButtonB` to move a distance x vertically downward away from it.

Comment: What troubles do you have with it? In net a lot of tutorials witch explain how to work with autolayout. Eg: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 0):

```
// Using Autolayout.

UIButton *buttonA, *buttonB;
UIView *fatherView; // The superview of buttonA and B.( The view where they are inside).
CGFloat distance;
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:buttonB attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:buttonA attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:distance];

[fatherView addConstraint:constraint];

// Without autolayout, maybe more easy.
buttonB.center = CGPointMake(buttonA.center.x, buttonA.center.y + distance);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt response. I adjusted my constraints accordingly, and now I am having an issue with the bottom of the cell, how should I solve that to make the cell expand to fit the new cell height? There is already also a constraint between the like button and the bottom of the cell. Here is an image: https://docs.google.com/document/d/12ZyVM1nHA9Zvs1G51rfNPLPZQ6J2BIkwcvm6UnM1muM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you are develop to iOS 8. You can use:     self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0; // Your default dimension
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

Comment: But all your cell must implement auto layout. The option: Implement delegate method: -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath